# Accessig array in django template

Tags: django

I have one for loop. And inside i want to access to other variable (array) by foorloop.counter0. How? I have tried like this: {{otherVariable.foorloop.counter0}} but nothing.

And like this works: {{otherVariable.0}}

Comment: what is exactly that you need that for? as: can you give us a bit more of context on what you're trying to accomplish, so maybe we can help you figure out a better approach for it?

Comment: Your question is rather confusing, please add code samples.

Comment: i have two arrays and they have the same number of elements. I want to iterate through one array and get corresponding element from another..

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom template filter (http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2740/) like

```
{{ otherVariable|get_at_index:forloop.counter0 }
```

or use the built-in 'slice' template tag (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice)

```
{{otherVariable|slice forloop.counter0 }}
```

### How to define custom templatetags/filters

Reference - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout

Your custom tags and filters will live in a module inside the templatetags directory, say in a file named 'custom_utils/py'

And in your template you would use the following:
    {% load  custom_utils %}

Comment: Thanks! just one thing where to define that tag? in what file?

Comment: np, Updated answer with that info.